# Change Webhooks information in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

Is it possible to filter/change the information provided for webhooks in WooCommerce?
The task is as follows: I am using WooCommerce as an online store platform and utilizing an external service via API that receives information for each order through WooCommerce via webhooks. The information received includes:

```
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Topic] => order.updated
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Resource] => order
                        [X-WC-Webhook-Event] => updated
```

Is it possible to filter the information and transmit it as processed information for webhooks?
Is it possible, with suitable source code for the function.php file in WooCommerce, to change the information for a given order made for a country within the EU other than Bulgaria? In other words, if a customer places an order and is outside Bulgaria, to calculate the total value of the product + VAT and send it with 0% VAT only to Webhooks?

Example:
A customer from Germany buys an LED lamp for 10 euros, a tax of 19% is applied, and the value becomes 11.90 euros. These 11.90 euros should be sent via Webhook as information at 0% VAT, as the tax is already included in the amount of 11.90 euros. It is important that the external application I use with Webhooks receives the total amount with the tax and receives that it is at 0%.

The actual information should not be changed in WooCommerce, only the information sent through WebHooks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-webhook.php` file, there's a filter called "woocommerce_webhook_payload", which should allow you to update the data before it is sent.

```php
/**
 * Change webhook data before sending to the endpoint.
 * 
 * @filter woocommerce_webhook_payload
 * @priority 10
 * @arguments 4
 * 
 * @param array $payload
 * @param \WC_Order|\WC_Product|WP_User $resource
 * @param int $resource_id
 * @param string $webhook_id
 * @return array New payload
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_webhook_payload', function($payload, $resource, $resource_id, $webhook_id) {
    // Do stuff.
    return $payload;
}, 10, 4);
```

If you need to add new headers instead, you can use the "woocommerce_webhook_http_args" filter instead.